# Conflicting getter definitions for property in Jackson 2.2.3

Tags: json, jackson

For simplicity here is a simple class:

```
class GetterMethodsObject {

    int id = 10;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    // @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isId() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Serializing this object should give:

```
{"id":10}
```

as there is public getter method. Usage example:

```
mapper=new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
```

But I am getting exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
Conflicting getter definitions for property "id": org.citi.facility.GetterMethodsObject#isId(0 params) vs org.citi.facility.GetterMethodsObject#getId(0 params)
```

As `id` is `Integer` so, I am expecting `Jackson` to call `getId()` method but not `isId()`. `isId()` method should be called only if id is boolean? Even I put `@JsonIgnore` it is not helping. I can not change actual object. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

`Jackson` library checks getter/setters methods for serializing/deserializing. You can omit this annoying bug by below dirty hack. You have to use two annotations:

1. `@JsonIgnore` - tell `Jackson` to ignore this property
2. `@JsonProperty("isId")` - tell `Jackson` to use this method name in serialization process. It looks like `Jackson` found collision because it found two methods and these two methods link to one field - `id`.

Your `POJO` class should look like below:

```
class GetterMethodsObject {

    private int id = 10;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonProperty("isId")
    public boolean isId() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Another solution: you should rename `isId` method because it is confusing. You should consider: `hasId` or even better `hasValidId`. I do not know what your's `isId` method is doing but you should give much more information in method name.