# How to ignore "Is' methods with Jackson 2.2.3

Tags: json, jackson

A simple class has "is" methods and "get" methods. I would like `Jackson` to ignore calling all "is" methods.

I tried by setting `ObjectMapper`'s visibility by setting as

```
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.IS_GETTER, Visibility.NONE);
```

But it is still considering the `is-getter` methods, why?

`Jackson` serializes getter methods and public variables. Is it possible to indicate `Jackson` to call only public getter methods but not serialize variables?

Comment: As to your second question: yes, it is possible to prevent use of `public` variables; using `@JsonAutoDetect` or `mapper.setVisibility()`, similar to how getters/is-getters discovery may be prevented.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider `@JsonAutoDetect` annotation. For example, (using POJO class from this question: [Conflicting getter definitions for property in Jackson 2.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495617/conflicting-getter-definitions-for-property-in-jackson-2-2-3) solution could look like this:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(isGetterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
class GetterMethodsObject {

    private int id = 10;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public boolean isId() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectWriter objectWriter = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();
System.out.println(objectWriter.writeValueAsString(new GetterMethodsObject()));
```

Above program prints:

```
{
  "id" : 10
}
```