# Jackson does not recognize weird property names after upgrade

Tags: kotlin, jackson, jackson-databind

After upgrading to Jackson 2.12.3, weirdly named Kotlin properties don't seem to be supported anymore:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Conflicting getter definitions for property "fSRI": com.example.ModelRow#getFSRI-SECTION() vs com.example.ModelRow#getFSRI-ID()
```

Full test case:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.convertValue
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class JacksonTest {

    @Test
    fun doTest() {
        val map = mapOf( "FSRI-SECTION" to "1", "FSRI-ID" to "1234")
        objectMapper().convertValue<MyModel>(map)
    }

    data class MyModel(
        val `FSRI-ID`: String?,
        val `FSRI-SECTION`: Int?
    )

    private fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
        return ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(KotlinModule(nullToEmptyCollection = true, nullIsSameAsDefault = true))
            .registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
            .registerModule(Jdk8Module())
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
            .configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false)
    }

}
```

It worked fine with 2.11.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable matching by fields not by `getters`. You can define this for the `ObjectMapper`:

```
private fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
    val mapper = ObjectMapper()
        .registerModule(KotlinModule(nullToEmptyCollection = true, nullIsSameAsDefault = true))
        .registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
        .registerModule(Jdk8Module())
        .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
        .configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false)

    return mapper.setVisibility(mapper.visibilityChecker
        .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
        .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY))
}
```

Or annotate only given class:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = NONE, fieldVisibility = ANY)
data class MyModel(
```

In both cases it should work and print:

```
MyModel(FSRI-ID=1234, FSRI-SECTION=1)
```

See also:

- [Why @JsonProperty not work for camel case properties in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68623042/why-jsonproperty-not-work-for-camel-case-properties-in-kotlin/68624348#68624348)
- [How to ignore "Is' methods with Jackson 2.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495838/how-to-ignore-is-methods-with-jackson-2-2-3/22520436#22520436)